# JSF Inject bean based on the day of the week

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have a primefaces datatable that has to display data based on which day of the week it  is.
I currently have a bean that checks the day;

```
 private AbstractDayController day;
 private int dayint;

 public AbstractDayController getDay() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    dayint = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    switch(dayint) {
        case Calendar.MONDAY:
            day = new MondayController();
        break;
        case Calendar.TUESDAY:
            day = new TuesdayController();
        break;
        case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
            day = new WednesdayController();
        break;
        case Calendar.THURSDAY:
            day = new ThursdayController();
        break; 
        case Calendar.FRIDAY:
            day = new FridayController();
        break;
        case Calendar.SATURDAY:
            day = new SaturdayController();             
        break;
    }
    return day;
}
```

My idea was to then retrieve the right bean by calling;

`<p:dataTable value="#{SetDay.day.dayTasks}" var="task">`

Where SetDay is the Bean containing the code and dayTasks is a list of objects from the relevant Bean. However this method is giving me a nullpointerException.

The Monday-Saturday controllers are subclasses of AbstractDayController.

I get a nullpointer exception on this method in the ThursdayController;

```
@Inject
private ThursdayDAO dayDAO;

@Override
public List<Thursday> getDayTasks() {
    this.dayTasks = this.dayDAO.findAll();
    return this.dayTasks;
}
```

dayDAO is resolving to null. If I for example go with #{ThursdayController.dayTasks} directly everything loads up fine without exceptions.

I really don't want to recreate the table for every bean, if possible, I would like to only call the relevant one in this requestscoped bean.

All help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I have temporarily solved this by injecting every day-controller into the managedbean and use them in the switch-case. It's ugly, but it works;

```
@Inject
private MondayController monday;
@Inject
private TuesdayController tuesday;
@Inject
private WednesdayController wednesday;
@Inject
private ThursdayController thursday;
@Inject
private FridayController friday;
@Inject
private SaturdayController saturday;

private List dayTasks;

private int dayint;



public List getDayTasks() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    dayint = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    switch(dayint) {
        case Calendar.MONDAY:
            dayTasks = monday.getDayTasks();
        case Calendar.TUESDAY:
            dayTasks = tuesday.getDayTasks();
        case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
            dayTasks = wednesday.getDayTasks();
        case Calendar.THURSDAY:
            dayTasks = thursday.getDayTasks();
        case Calendar.FRIDAY:
            dayTasks = friday.getDayTasks();
        case Calendar.SATURDAY:
            dayTasks = saturday.getDayTasks();
    }
    return dayTasks;
}
```

Then call it via #{SetDay.dayTasks}

Suggestions for a cleaner way to do this is most welcome.
Is there any way to programmatically inject beans? Without annotation?
If so, I could do that in the switch-case instead.

Comment: is ThursdayController managed by the container. Have you annotated it properly.

Comment: Yes it all works if I just specify the right bean manually via the xhtml. Like  #{ThursdayController.dayTasks}. So there must be something wrong with how I call the bean from the SetDay bean

Comment: I'm not sure how @Inject would work on something that is instantiated through 'new'. Does you other DayController have any specific implementation???

Comment: DayController has no injection, only class type, name and list of tasks. The EJB injection only happens in the subclasses.

Comment: This is so unusual :-)

Comment: Please tell me if my design is flawed. I'm still relatively new to Java and would appreciate any advice as to how this can be done.

Comment: What I meant was  when you do a 'new ThursdayController();' it is not managed and hence @Inject will not work. I'm however surprised how your other classes in Monday-Saturday Controllers work. Its seems only the ThursdayController does not work. Is that true?

Comment: No, but that pretty much explains it. When the Controllers are accessed via the managed bean the injection doesn't work, thus the variable returns null. I have to set which Controller to use directly through the JSF .xhtml for the injection to work. Any way to get around this? Is there for example a switch-case JSF equivalent? To use in the .xhtml directly?

Answer (score -2):

which JSF implementation u r using ? some implementations looks at the field before invoking the method throw reflication and since your AbstractDayController day is defined as NULL

Try this ,

```
public AbstractDayController getDay() {
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
dayint = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
switch(dayint) {
    case Calendar.MONDAY:
        return new MondayController();
    case Calendar.TUESDAY:
        return new TuesdayController();
    case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
        return new WednesdayController();
    case Calendar.THURSDAY:
        return new ThursdayController();
    case Calendar.FRIDAY:
        return new FridayController();
    case Calendar.SATURDAY:
        return new SaturdayController();             
}
```

}

Comment: I use netbeans, so I just selected JSF as framework when creating the project. Tried your method but still got nullpointer. I'm pretty sure it's the dayDAO that is resolved to null seeing as it points to line 79 in my ThursdayController. Which is the ' this.dayTasks = this.dayDAO.findAll(); ' line. Are there any requirements for the @Inject annotation to work when it's not called directly from the JSF .xhtml file?

Comment: i'm not sure about javax.inject for me i'm using spring autoware.you can check this maybe it will help sorry because the first method did't work for you http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html